# Flask Application Structure & Apache Integration

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualhost, wsgi

I currently have a Flask application structured as follows. I'm looking to try to get away from the development server and use Apache instead although I am slightly confused by the various tutorials I am reading.

[image: Flask Tree View].

- Sandbox is a directory containing my various packages. At the moment, there is only one package named *decorators*.
- runserver.py simply starts the application as follows:

`from decorators import app
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)`

- ***init**.py* simply instantiates my application object:

`from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)
 import decorators.views`

- views.py contains all of my actual decorators `(@app.route)` etc for the package named 'decorators'. (Obviously this contains a circular import back to my application object).

So far so good, everything works. **First question**, am I right in saying that in order to make available multiple packages, I simply import them within my runserver.py file? Something like:

`from decorators import app
 from anotherpackage import app
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)`

If not, how would I go about using multiple packages simultaneously?

**Second question**, when integrating Flask into Apache as shown here: 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/ I need to create a VirtualHost: fair enough. However, within a VirtualHost, I would need to point towards an application, would I point this towards my runserver.py and rename it to a .wsgi file?

Been scratching my head with this one for a while so any help you could give me on either question would be amazing. Thanks in advance!